# Hiding (or Displaying) Rows in SSRS Based off a Field Value

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I'd like to only display certain rows on my report using SSRS if the field value of EMID=3 or EMID=Null.  Or if it would be easier, to hide rows where EMID in (1,2)

I right + clicked the row -> Row Visibility -> Show or Hide Based on an Expression and created this expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!EMID.Value=1 Or Fields!EMID.Value=2,True,False)
```

But that does not hide the rows I am looking to hide.  Any suggestions on what I did wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the times issue with the `SSRS` value matching expressions are the data types of the values that creates the problems or undesired result. 
In your case your `EMID` field might be coming as the `string` so you need to make sure that it is convert back to the `Int` before matching. For that matter always right your expressions in `SSRS` using type conversion so your expression can be on safer side.

```
 =IIF(CInt(Fields!EMID.Value)=1 Or CInt(Fields!EMID.Value)= 2,True,False)
```

Comment: I was comparing 2 strings the following wasnt working :-

=IIF(Fields!line_name.Value = "dontdisplay",true,false)

but then this worked :-

=IIF(Fields!line_name.Value.ToString = "dontdisplay".ToString,true,false)

go figure!